# display circle in android using drawarc method

Tags: android

how to create circle in android using drawarc method. 
or
how to split a circle in 6 parts. each part contain different color.

Comment: if you give startangle=0 endangle=-360 in drawarc method. it will display circle. but i want to display the circle in 6 different arc in different color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an array holding 6 colors (paint), then use a loop to create the 6 parts of the arc

Like

```
  for(int i = 0; i < color.length; i++){
     drawArc (RectF oval, 60*i , 60*(i+1), True, color(i))
  }
```

Or

```
  for(int i = 0; i < color.length; i++){
     drawArc (RectF oval, (360/color.length)*i , (360/color.length)*(i+1), True, color(i))
  }
```